# Will an inline function with no code in it affect the outputted binary?

Tags: c++, debugging, inline, c-preprocessor

So, in short, what I'm trying to do is make the debug version of my program output additional information. But rather than having to check

```
#IFDEF DEBUG
...
#ENDIF
```

in the middle of high level code, I would prefer to do something more like this

```
Debug::PrintDebugMessage(...);
```

So my question is, if I made this hypothetical function like so

```
inline static void PrintDebugMessage(...);
void PrintDebugMessage(...)
{
   #IFDEF DEBUG
   ...
   #ENDIF
}
```

would the resulting program change when DEBUG is not defined? That is, if I called this function while DEBUG was not defined, would anything happen low-level code-wise, or would the compiler simply omit the blank function? (I apologize if I worded this confusingly)

Comment: Did you try comparing the .o files?

Comment: Isn't `inline` invalid with sole declarations??

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency until you have a slow-down problem, and it has been proven that your call is the issue. Worrying about efficiency when your code is probably fast enough is a waste of effort. An optimization that small would probably only save microseconds per century.

Comment: No it would not, maybe (and I just say this to cover all possibilities) the compiler will output a NOP

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: There is still the problem of the argument list. `PrintDebugMessage(expensive_computation() );` must have all the side effects that `expensive_computation()` has, regardless of what `PrintDebugMessage` looks like.

Comment: Arkadiy: I don't know how to compare .o files ._.

Comment: Damien Black: I'm more worried about the concept really, but thanks :]

Comment: Dani: Using gcc/g++ 4.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just implement a `PrintDebugMessage(...)` macro?

You define:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#  define PrintDebugMessage(...) \
     <Implement>
#else
#  define PrintDebugMessage(...)
#endif
```

You will get no code generated in your release binary but, probably more importantly, you can make use of the `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` macros as well as the `__func__` function. These are great for debugging but are only useful in macros.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the OP should try compiling it and inspecting the assembly. With any modern compiler, the release binary will optimize it out. If he uses a debug (`DEBUG=-g`) build with minimal optimization level (`CCFLAGS+=-O0`) he will get a context change back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
inline void PrintDebugMessage(..) {
#ifdef DEBUG
...
#endif
}
```

A inline function which does nothing will does nothing.
Be Aware that side effect of argument computation are still executed.
So it is a correct way.

An other method which doesn't call argument computation (in non-debug) is

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
# define PrintDebugMessage(..) PrintDebugMessage_implementation(..)
inline void PrintDebugMessage_implementation(..) {
    ..
}
#else
# define PrintDebugMessage(..) do { } while (false) /* Do nothing */
#endif
```